# Laravel: getting blade components syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-components

I am learning laravel on Laracast however I am having some issues

I have this  code on file `components/layout.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Host Cloud Template - Services</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{$content}}
</body>
```

And this on `main.blade.php` which is the page the view redirects to

```
<x-layout content = "Hello There">


</x-layout>
```

For some reason Laravel is returning this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file (View: C:\laragon\www\Conferencias\resources\views\template\main.blade.php)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `content="Hello There"` ?

Comment: If  I remove the content this error will disapear but then the page won't have a content.

Comment: Try `<x-layout content="Hello There"/>` since there is no body to the component element. Also make sure to clear view caches.

Comment: Also the error message should include the location of the actual rendered PHP file; take a look at it to see if the problem becomes clearer.

Comment: it is fixed, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem,  I had a space between `content` and  `="Hello There"` by removing it and leaving it like `content="Hello There"` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I crossed a similar problem, i was calling my component as **`<x-menu>`** closing the tag as   **`<x-menu />`** solved the problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).